# Airflow doesn't pick up FAILED status of Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I'm running Airflow on Kubernetes using this Helm chart: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/1.5.0

I've written a very simple DAG just to test some things. It looks like this:

```
default_args={
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG(
    'my-dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='simple dag',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=datetime(2022, 4, 21),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example']
) as dag:

    t1 = SparkKubernetesOperator(
        task_id='spark-pi',
        trigger_rule="all_success",
        depends_on_past=False,
        retries=3,
        application_file="spark-pi.yaml",
        namespace="my-ns",
        kubernetes_conn_id="myk8s",
        api_group="sparkoperator.k8s.io",
        api_version="v1beta2",
        do_xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag
    )

    t2 = SparkKubernetesOperator(
        task_id='other-spark-job',
        trigger_rule="all_success",
        depends_on_past=False,
        retries=3,
        application_file=other-spark-job-definition,
        namespace="my-ns",
        kubernetes_conn_id="myk8s",
        api_group="sparkoperator.k8s.io",
        api_version="v1beta2",
        dag=dag
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

When I run the DAG from the Airflow UI, the first task Spark job (`t1`, spark-pi) gets created and is immediately marked as successful, and then Airflow launches the second (t2) task right after that. This can be seen in the web UI:

[image]

What you're seeing is the status of the two tasks in 5 separate DAG runs, as well as their total status (the circles). The middle row of the image shows the status of `t1`, which is `"success"`.

**However**, the actual spark-pi pod of `t1` launched by the Spark operator fails on every run, and its status can be seen by querying the Sparkapplication resource on Kubernetes:

```
$ kubectl get sparkapplications/spark-pi-2022-04-28-2 -n my-ns -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2",
    "kind": "SparkApplication",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-04-29T13:28:02Z",
        "generation": 1,
        "name": "spark-pi-2022-04-28-2",
        "namespace": "my-ns",
        "resourceVersion": "111463226",
        "uid": "23f1c8fb-7843-4628-b22f-7808b562f9d8"
    },
    "spec": {
        "driver": {
            "coreLimit": "1500m",
            "cores": 1,
            "labels": {
                "version": "2.4.4"
            },
            "memory": "512m",
            "volumeMounts": [
                {
                    "mountPath": "/tmp",
                    "name": "test-volume"
                }
            ]
        },
        "executor": {
            "coreLimit": "1500m",
            "cores": 1,
            "instances": 1,
            "labels": {
                "version": "2.4.4"
            },
            "memory": "512m",
            "volumeMounts": [
                {
                    "mountPath": "/tmp",
                    "name": "test-volume"
                }
            ]
        },
        "image": "my.google.artifactory.com/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.4",
        "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
        "mainApplicationFile": "local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar",
        "mainClass": "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
        "mode": "cluster",
        "restartPolicy": {
            "type": "Never"
        },
        "sparkVersion": "2.4.4",
        "type": "Scala",
        "volumes": [
            {
                "hostPath": {
                    "path": "/tmp",
                    "type": "Directory"
                },
                "name": "test-volume"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "applicationState": {
            "errorMessage": "driver container failed with ExitCode: 1, Reason: Error",
            "state": "FAILED"
        },
        "driverInfo": {
            "podName": "spark-pi-2022-04-28-2-driver",
            "webUIAddress": "172.20.23.178:4040",
            "webUIPort": 4040,
            "webUIServiceName": "spark-pi-2022-04-28-2-ui-svc"
        },
        "executionAttempts": 1,
        "lastSubmissionAttemptTime": "2022-04-29T13:28:15Z",
        "sparkApplicationId": "spark-3335e141a51148d7af485457212eb389",
        "submissionAttempts": 1,
        "submissionID": "021e78fc-4754-4ac8-a87d-52c682ddc483",
        "terminationTime": "2022-04-29T13:28:25Z"
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `status` section, we have `"state": "FAILED"`. Still, Airflow marks it as successful and thus runs t2 right after it, which is not what we want when defining `t2` as dependent on (downstream of) `t1`.

Why does Airflow see `t1` as successful even though the Spark job itself fails?

Answer (score 1):

That's the implementation. If you see the code for the operator it is basically a submit and forget job. To monitor the status you use SparkkubernetesSensor

```py
       t2 = SparkKubernetesSensor(
            task_id="spark_monitor",
            application_name="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='spark-job-full-refresh.spark_full_refresh') ['metadata']['name'] }}",
            attach_log=True,
        )
```

I have tried to create a custom operator that combines both but it does not work very well via inheritance because they are slightly different execution patterns, so it needs to be created from scratch. But for all purposes and intents, the Sensor works perfectly, just adds unneeded lines to code.

Answer (score 0):

@Islam Elsayed I am deploying sparkapp using airflow2.6.0 in k8s using sparkKubernetesOperator. In this case, even though the sparkapp is created but  fails for any reason, the task is marked as successful.

I tried using the SparkKubernetesSensor to keep track of sparkjob status. But the sensor task fails with the error

```
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 852, in _fail_with_undefined_error
    raise self._undefined_exception(self._undefined_message)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'metadata'
[2024-03-13T08:17:39.510+0000] {taskinstance.py:1368} INFO - Marking task
```

When checked, the xcom of the sparkkubernetesoperator task is empty

I also checked for the task that use just a bash operator to echo hello,in that case xcom returns value

This is the dag

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.spark_kubernetes import SparkKubernetesOperator
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.sensors.spark_kubernetes import SparkKubernetesSensor
import os

default_args={
   'depends_on_past': False,
}

with DAG(
   'spark-dag',
   default_args=default_args,
   description='sample spark dag',
   schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
   start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 17),
   catchup=False,
   tags=['maps']
) as dag:
   t1 = SparkKubernetesOperator(
       task_id='sample-spark',
       application_file="spark/sample-spark/sample-spark.yaml",
       namespace="incentives",
       do_xcom_push=True,
       dag=dag
   )

   t2 = SparkKubernetesSensor(
      task_id='spark-sensor',
      namespace="incentives",
      application_name="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='sample-spark')['metadata']['name'] }}",
      attach_log=True,
      poke_interval=5,
      dag=dag
      )
   t1 >> t2
```